# trigger to autoincrement from specific value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-update

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
   ON  persons
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN
        UPDATE t1
            SET Externalid= ('MN' + t.ExternalID) 
        FROM inserted AS t
            INNER JOIN Persons AS t1 ON t.PersonUid = t1.PersonUid
    END
END
```

I want to set specific 'START' value to externalid example 45 so that this update query generates MN46 (auto increment to next externalid). As of now it just checks last auto generated externalid and set externalid accordingly.

Comment: `plsql` is for **Oracle** (PL/SQL) - the other tags indicate **SQL Server** (T-SQL) - so which is it now, really?

Comment: Based on the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` seems like it's T-SQL not PL/SQL.

Comment: If you want an automatically incrementing value, why not use an `IDENTITY`?

Comment: @larnu yes tsql it is. Can you tell me how to use identity? I want to autoincrement in this script from specific value.

Comment: A quick search of "IDENTITY SQL Server" will give you the documentation. What about it said documentation didn't you understand, @Div26 ?

Comment: Because we expect you to research *before* you ask, as the website tells you to do @Div26 . As for incorrectly tagging, that is a problem because it makes the question far harder to answer when we don't know what technology you are really using. But yes, if you read the documentation it'll tell you **exactly** how to use `IDENTITY`. If you didn't understand it, that's fine but explain what about it you didn't understand.

Comment: Thanks ,I get that. Obviously I tried and research before I came here and was looking for solution which I can use in my update query. I am not allowed to modify table and IDENTITY cannot be used. I want to use above trigger to accomplish that.This trigger auto increment from last generated externalid but I want it to increment from certain number.

Comment: Then I would suggest talking to someone who *can* modify the column, @Div26 . An `IDENTITY` is really what you need here. Though you *could* use a `SEQUENCE` in a `TRIGGER` it is far from the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a default value and a sequence.  Eg

```
create sequence Persons_seq start with 1 increment by 1

create table Persons
(
  ExternalId varchar(20) primary key default (concat('MN',(next value for Persons_seq))),
  a int
)
```

Or you could do the same thing in a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
   ON  persons
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Persons
        SET ExternalId = concat('MN',(next value for Persons_seq))
        WHERE PersonUid in (select PersonUid from inserted)
    END
END
```

Comment: David, I have to make use of only trigger to do that. We are not allowed to modify table structures.

Comment: I would have to ask if I am allowed to create sequence (again schema level change) but this helps. Thank you David.

Comment: A trigger is already a _significant_ change to the database design, and you can put the sequence in a different schema if you want.